# Bridge does not get IP from DHCP server on boot

Tags: networking, 16.04, dhcp, network-bridge

I have a bridge created on my ubunut 16.04 box. The bridge does not get an IP from my DHCP server on the network on boot.

/etc/network/interfaces :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)  
auto br0  
iface br0 inet dhcp  
    bridge-ifaces eno1  
    bridge-ports eno1  
    up ifconfig eno1 up  
iface eno1 inet manual  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback
```

When the machine is booted, it has no connection to the LAN, there is no internet connection. The IP's on my lan are 192.168.11.xx. The IP of the bridge on boot is 10.255.212.1.

On boot:

```
bas@Viky:~$ ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:aa:14:72:d0:af  
          inet addr:10.255.212.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::feaa:14ff:fe72:d0af/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:397 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:212 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:506043 (506.0 KB)  TX bytes:18913 (18.9 KB)

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:aa:14:72:d0:af  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1191 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:951 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1285826 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:108134 (108.1 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7c00000-f7c20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:189 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:189 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:13790 (13.7 KB)  TX bytes:13790 (13.7 KB)

vethVOCFUV Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:4e:32:1f:b7:f4  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc4e:32ff:fe1f:b7f4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:743 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:793 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:85052 (85.0 KB)  TX bytes:776556 (776.5 KB)
```

After boot this can be corrected by ifdown -a and ifup -a.

```
bas@Viky:~$ sudo ifdown -a
[sudo] password for bas: 
Killed old client process
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/br0/fc:aa:14:72:d0:af
Sending on   LPF/br0/fc:aa:14:72:d0:af
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPRELEASE on br0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67 (xid=0x79a7a104)
```

Get the network up:

```
bas@Viky:~$ sudo ifup -a

Waiting for br0 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 32 seconds).
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/br0/fc:aa:14:72:d0:af
Sending on   LPF/br0/fc:aa:14:72:d0:af
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x177d1021)
DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x177d1021)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.11.28 on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x21107d17)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.11.28 from 192.168.11.1
DHCPACK of 192.168.11.28 from 192.168.11.1
bound to 192.168.11.28 -- renewal in 274608 seconds.
```

I don't understand why the bridge does not get an IP address from the DHCP server on boot.
Can anyone help met out with this please?
Where do I start on this networking challange?

Bas

(Because I did not get any response on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774917/bridge-networking-lxd-emby-server-configuration-trouble) question, I figured it is to broad. Therefore made this sub question.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe for your bridge section, it should look like:

*It is bridge_ports not bridge-ports*

```
auto br0  
iface br0 inet dhcp   
    bridge_ports eno1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0 
iface eno1 inet manual
```

More information can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge).

---

Example from my system:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# The network interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
   bridge_ports eth0
   bridge_stp off
   bridge_fd 0
   bridge_maxwait 0
iface eth0 inet manual
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback



$ ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:85:94:46:a4  
          inet addr:10.0.0.100  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:195 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:211 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:39400 (39.4 KB)  TX bytes:27433 (27.4 KB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:85:94:46:a4  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:278675 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:263759 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:110002223 (110.0 MB)  TX bytes:408874062 (408.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:64269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:23474196 (23.4 MB)  TX bytes:23474196 (23.4 MB)
```

---

Hope this helps!