# no primary network interface declared for /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, network-bridge, ifconfig

Looking at setting up a [bridge network](https://askubuntu.com/q/979459/45156), I switched from wi-fi to a wired connection.  However, [my networking](https://askubuntu.com/q/980382/45156) is different than described:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Can and should I add a `The primary network interface` as [described](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KvmWithBridge)?

general reference:

[What is the correct syntax for /etc/network/interfaces?](https://askubuntu.com/q/245806/45156)

[Bridge does not get IP from DHCP server on boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/775575/45156)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This works with `virsh` (rather, `virt-install`):

```
$ sudo ifup br0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/br0/c8:9c:dc:28:86:ca
Sending on   LPF/br0/c8:9c:dc:28:86:ca
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x6a928a4c)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.6 on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x4c8a926a)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.6 from 192.168.1.1
DHCPACK of 192.168.1.6 from 192.168.1.1
bound to 192.168.1.6 -- renewal in 37710 seconds.

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp   
    bridge_ports eno1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
iface eno1 inet manual
```